# В чем ошибка при умножении на 3 в полях галуа 2^8

Tags: c++

Я написал функцию для умножения на 3 в полях галуа 2^8

```
uint8_t gmull(uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t byte = value;
    for(int i = 0;i < 2;i++)
    {
        byte <<= 1;
        if(byte >= 0x80) { byte ^= 0x1b; }
    }
    return byte;
}
```

При вызове функции `gmull(0xd4)` возвращает `102(если в десятичной системе)` но если полагаться на данную функцию(взято с гитхаба)

```
unsigned char gmul(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
    unsigned char p = 0;
    unsigned char counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++) {
        unsigned char hi_bit_set;
        if((b & 1) == 1)
            p ^= a;
        hi_bit_set = (a & 0x80);
        a <<= 1;
        if(hi_bit_set == 0x80)
            a ^= 0x1b;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Должно возвращать `103` а не `102` так в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte <<= 1;
if(byte >= 0x80) { byte ^= 0x1b; }
```

условие `if(byte >= 0x80)` у вас идёт после изменения переменной `byte <<= 1;`. А в оригинале спрашивается прошлое значение :

```
hi_bit_set = (a & 0x80);
a <<= 1;
if(hi_bit_set == 0x80)
    a ^= 0x1b;
```

Тяжело найти минимальное исправление в вашей функции. Написал свою :

```
uint8_t gmull(uint8_t value) {
  uint8_t b = ( value << 1 ) ^ value ;
  if ( value >= 0x80 )
    return (b ^ 0x1b);
  return b ;
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример мне кажеться интересным но я не очень понимаю для чего после сдвига на 1 `value << 1` нужно полученое значение xor'ть на `value`?

Comment: Это оптимизация цикла с двумя проходами, в первом проходе результат равен `value`, а во втором `xor` с `value<<1`. Так как функция `xor` имеет свойство симметричности, то можно это сделать и перед `if`-ом и после.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понимаю, в моей функции в первом проходе цикла `byte` сдвигаеться на 1 а не просто равен `value` после идёт условие `byte ^= 0x1b`, во втором проходе `byte` снова сдвигаеться на 1 и снова идёт условие, но нигде нет xor'a на изначальный полученый аргумент `value`

Comment: В оригинале если число `b=3` нечётное `if((b & 1) == 1)`  , то результат `p` ксориться с `a`. То-есть при первом проходе результат `p == a`. Дальше число `a`   умножается на два `a <<= 1;` , `b=3` делиться пополам `b>>=1;`. Второй проход : результат ксориться с новым значением `a`. `p ^= a;` `p` - был равен `a` , `a` стал равен `a := a<<1` и `p` ксориться с новым `a<<1`. То-есть `p == a ^ (a << 1)`.

Comment: Вы своём алгоритме очень много переделали и он не делает ничего как должно быть.